# How to generate a dynamic IonModal using useIonModal

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a modal which is being used as a form. This is working correctly.
However, when a button is clicked in this modal, a network request is done, and then the results of this request I would like to show in a new modal.
This new modal will also have a cancel button, and a confirm button. So I also need to pass the result of this modal back to the main modal.
Here is some pseudo code to help you understand my situation.
I am using Ionic with react.

```
// I want the component of this modal to be dynamic
// I also need to somehow introduce resolve that is from the promise that is launching this modal
const thisIsNotDynamic = <>
    <IonText>This needs to be dynamic</IonText>
    <IonButton onclick={()=>{resolve(false)}}>Cancel</IonButton> 
    <IonButton onclick={()=>{resolve(true)}}>Confirm</IonButton>
</>

const [showModal] = useIonModal(thisIsNotDynamic);

// Pseudo parent modal
<IonModal>
    <IonButton onclick={()=>{check()}}/>
</IonModal>
// Pseudo function called by parent modal
const check = () => {
    // Do network check
    // Put the result in a variable called result
    const continue = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        return showModal()
    });
    if(continue)
        // Continue stuff
    else
        // Do not continue stuff
}
```

I cannot add the useIonModal hook to the inside of the function because it throws an error.
How could I achieve a dynamic modal, that also resolves a promise?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Inline Modals, you need to use controller modals.

Comment: I am trying to use controller modals. The parent of the modal is an inline modal.

Comment: How this answer is supposed to help?

Comment: you should be using controller modals all around if you're nesting modals. @akuma8 thats how it helps ;P